# Is there degradation having multiple web socket clients

Tags: c#, websocket

I have a 'super client' app that sends small jpegs to my server using web sockets.

On my server I relay these small jpegs to other 'minor clients' that are connected.

At the moment I use port 8080 to upload to my server and I use port 8081 to relay/download to my clients.

**I could have other 'super clients' uploading to my server (on the same port).**

Now, will increasing the number of these 'super clients' degrade performance especially in terms of the speed the 'minor clients' receive these images or should I be using a different port for each 'super client' or will this not make any difference?

Of course I will be doing my own testing to find this out but I thought I would post the question to see what my peers say about all this.